# Bad shading result when applying material

Tags: opengl

I've got an openGL 3d scene with two simple objects (glutSolidCube and glutSolidTeapot). When I set up the lights with GL_COLOR_MATERIAL enabled, I get the following result:

[image]

Which is good. Then when I set up my own material like this:

```
//diffuse light color variables
GLfloat dlr = 0.4;
GLfloat dlg = 0.6;
GLfloat dlb = 0.9;

//ambient light color variables
GLfloat alr = 0.7;
GLfloat alg = 0.7;
GLfloat alb = 0.7;

//ambient light color variables
GLfloat slr = 0.4;
GLfloat slg = 0.4;
GLfloat slb = 0.4;


GLfloat DiffuseLight[]  = {dlr, dlg, dlb}; //set DiffuseLight[] to the specified values
GLfloat AmbientLight[]  = {alr, alg, alb}; //set AmbientLight[] to the specified values
GLfloat SpecularLight[] = {slr, slg, slb}; //set AmbientLight[] to the specified values

glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, (float *)&AmbientLight);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, (float *)&DiffuseLight);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, (float *)&SpecularLight);
```

I get this very different result, in which you can see it's not being shaded properly, it's like FLAT shading although I defined it as SMOOTH (Gouraud).

[image]

Where can the problem be? Is it on the material definition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to set [specular shininess](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glMaterial.xml).

`glMaterialf(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, 12.0f);`

Set it to 10...25 and it'll look much better/shinier. It won't look as good as per-pixel lighting, though. Default value for shininess is zero which will look exactly like what you see - i.e. ugly.

Answer (score 1):

> I get this very different result, in which you can see it's not being shaded properly, it's like FLAT shading although I defined it as SMOOTH (Gouraud).

Well, you got smooth shading. However the OpenGL fixed function pipeline evaluates illumination values only at the vertices, then performs barycentric interpolation over the face. The result you got is exactly what to expect.

What you want is per pixel/fragment illumination. Only way to get this is by using a shader (well, it's also possible by tinkering with the so called "texture combiner environment", but getting that one to work properly is a lot of hard work. Implementing a Phong illumination shader is a matter of minutes).

By changing your lighting and material settings you're just putting emphasis on the shortcommings of the Gouraud shading model.

Comment: Shaders have nothing to do with it. His problem is that he forgot to set shininess and default value is zero. With zero shininess, you'll get identically ugly effect even with per-pixel specular lighting.